# Latex version of this cv

Tags: resume

I want to write a CV with LaTeX and I'm wondering if someone could help me and give the beginning code of this CV:

[image]

I will inspire myself from it.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  What is specifically causing you trouble?  Can you center the first few lines as it is in the example, but don't know how to do the 'section' headings?  Is it the weird, 'double bullet' lists that are particularly difficult?  Normally, you are encouraged to ask for help with specific problems, not "Please do this (whole) thing for me".

Comment: @DG' I guess he knows, because that belongs to him too... does this fact make this question a duplicate? :)

Comment: Indeed, how curious! I didn’t see that…